# How to recode a range of values into a new column

Tags: dplyr

I am trying to recode a variable (diab) into a new variable (diab_bin).  I'd like observations with 1 to be recoded to 0, and 2:5 to be recoded as 1.

However, I can't even get past the first step of just recoding 1 to 0.

Here's what I've tried:

```
names<-c("A","B","C","D")
diab<-c(1,3,5,4)

data<-data.frame(names, diab)

data %>%
  mutate(diab, diab_bin = recode(`1`=`0`))
```

And then i get the error:  Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `diab_bin`.
ℹ `diab_bin = recode(`1`=`0`)`.
x object '0' not found

Any help appreciated!  New to R....thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!  Use case_when and between

```
data %>%
  mutate(diab_bin = case_when(
    diab==1 ~ 0,
    between(diab, 2,5) ~ 1
  ))
```